# How to get full SID from powershell AD module and run in SSIS

Tags: powershell, ssis

I m developing a SSIS package to get all disabled account from AD. I want to get the full SID and put into a file. But it not allow me to do that.

Right now I m having this code which works fine in my package:

```
-executionpolicy remotesigned -command "import-module activedirectory; search-adaccount -accountdisabled |ft SamAccountName, SID" >d:\scripts\disabledaccount\DisabledAccount.txt
```

But this only returns SID like: S-1-5-21-1219070818-4200922009-29827...

So I need the full SID. I tried to run this code in Powershell AD :

```
import-module activedirectory; search-adaccount -accountdisabled |ft SamAccountName,@{Label="SID";Expression={$_.SID};width=50;align="left"} >d:\scripts\disabledaccount\DisabledAccount.txt
```

and it works fine. but when I try to run it in SSIS package it doesn't work because of @{Label="SID";Expression={$_.SID};width=50;align="left"}  this part.

Can any one let me know what should I put there to get the full SID?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of 'ft' (`Format-Table`), use `Select-Object` instead. The Format-* cmdlets are actually manipulating the text to make it fit best in the console window; you don't want that. Just try

```
Search-ADAccount -AccountDisabled | Select-Object SamAccountName, SID
```

and see that that gets you.